# how to Refresh different controls on main form

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a windows form application and different number of the control on the form is WPF user control. I have put element host control on the windows form and this is loading my user control at startup.

What I want is to load and refresh different number of user control at certain time on main page. As I need fresh data to be loaded.